# Capturing video of an arbitrary Windows application

Tags: windows, video, video-capture

I am looking for a solution that can record video out of an arbitrary Windows application.

The main requirement is that the solution should be really easy to use: my foremost planned usage is that I'm going to let some marketing people grab sample clips of an application I wrote, with whatever data they want to use.

<sup>(The previous version of this app had video recording functionality built in, but due to changing the structure of the program, this stopped working. For more on that, see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339379/qt-mdi-app-with-opengl-how-to-grab-a-valid-screenshot). In the meantime, an external application ought to be ok for the users.)</sup>

Now FOSS would be great of course, but it's not an absolute requirement. As long as the solution just works, and is easy enough for anyone to use. It would be great if it did not advertise something else.

In case I could have some additional wishes, they would be:

- Possibility to control output quality (bit rate, frame rate?)
- Support for at least one such codec that is able to output clips that can be viewed on a vanilla Windows box, without having to download anything (well if the download is automatic and therefore easy enough for the user, that should be ok I guess)
- Still, it would be great if it *also* came with a portable output format

I just found [Jing](http://jingproject.com/), which seems to work well, but at least the free version is somewhat limited. Any alternatives that you would recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) is open source.

> CamStudio is able to record all screen and audio activity on your computer and create industry-standard AVI video files and using its built-in SWF Producer can turn those AVIs into lean, mean, bandwidth-friendly Streaming Flash videos (SWFs)

Comment: Thanks nik - CamStudio seems to be very much what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at [Ashampoo Snap 3](http://www2.ashampoo.com/webcache/html/1/product_2_0324___USD.htm). This program is able to capture videos from a movie, an application and from an area you can define. The video codec used is the Windows Media Video codec, you can choose there from v7 to v9. Also you are able to define the bit rate and the frame rate. If you want you can also use a mic for capturing your voice.

Ashampoo Snap is easy to use and you also have the benefit that you are able to capture screenshots. The price of 19,99 USD is IMHO affordable.

Unfortunately Ashampoo Snap isn't coming with a portable output format.

Comment: Yep, that kind of a price is not an issue; it's more the hassle of actually managing licenses to everyone who might need the program one day.