# What are the best tools to make screencast video tutorials?

Tags: video, desktop, recording, screen-capture, screencasts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capturing video of an arbitrary Windows application](https://superuser.com/questions/30544/capturing-video-of-an-arbitrary-windows-application)
>   [What is the best software for desktop recording?](https://superuser.com/questions/6801/what-is-the-best-software-for-desktop-recording)

I've a webpage with small image based jQuery animated tutorial for kids. Size of the DIV displaying animation is 640x425. What would be the best tool to capture this animation as video? I want to upload this video on Youtube.

Probably some tool which would allow me to select display area dimensions would be useful.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://superuser.com/questions/6801/what-is-the-best-software-for-desktop-recording

Answer (score 1):

Try [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/), it's free and fits your requirements.
If the recording performance is not good enough, install the CamStudio codec, which performs significantly better than the default.

Comment: But it has known malware right now.  :(  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamStudio#Malicious_Software

Comment: Oh, thats bad to hear. I checked with VirusTotal and it looks like the download from sourceforge is clean, while the download from camstudio.org is infected. But anyway, caution is advised...

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Jing](http://www.jingproject.com/) and it works like a charm.

*Free*, easy, fast and with an excellent GUI. Awesome piece of software.